# java mail attachments getting corrupted

Tags: jakarta-mail, email-attachments, corrupt-data

This is my code for attaching the files to the mail:

```
Multipart mp=new MimeMultipart("mixed");
BodyPart mbody=new MimeBodyPart();
mbody.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/html; charset=us-ascii");
mbody.setHeader("Content-Transfer-Encoding","7bit");
mbody.setContent(content2, "text/html");                                                   
mp.addBodyPart(mbody);                                        
for(File file:f){    
   BodyPart mbody2=new MimeBodyPart();
   DataSource ds=new FileDataSource(file.getAbsolutePath());
   mbody2.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(ds));
   mbody2.setFileName(ds.getName());
   mbody2.setHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/mixed");
   mbody2.setHeader("Content-Transfer-Encoding", "base64");                        
   mp.addBodyPart(mbody2);                        
}
m.setContent(mp);
```

`content2` is the html content I am embedding in the E-mail, and I am adding files from an arraylist `f`.

The problem here is that although the files get attached and I receive the E-mail fine, I am unable to open the attachments because the data is corrupt. This happens for all the files I've tried to attach like jpegs, pdfs, spreadsheets, word docs and txt files.

I read here: https://community.oracle.com/thread/1589120 that this could happen because JavaMail uses encoding that messes up the binary data of the file and adding `mbody2.setHeader("Content-Transfer-Encoding", "base64");` should fix the problem but that doesn't work for me.

Any ideas on what could be wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Time for some debugging...

First, remove all of the setHeader calls; some of them are wrong and none of them should be necessary.

Next, determine if the problem is on the sending end or the receiving end.  Try multiple mail readers to see if they all have problems with the attachments.

Try sending plain text attachments.  Are they also corrupted?

Post the [protocol trace](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#debug) showing what happens when you send a simple message with a simple attachment that fails, so we can see if the message is being constructed correctly.

What version of JavaMail are you using?

What mail reader are you using to view the attachments?

Comment: Taking out the headers did the trick.
Can you please explain why or how the headers messed up the email?
Thanks.

Comment: You were overriding the Content-Type for the attachment, which should've been appropriate for whatever type of file you were attaching, to say that it was a multipart.  It most certainly was not; it was **contained** in a multipart.  The others were just unnecessary since JavaMail will (almost always) choose the correct content type and encoding for you.